# Android Google Cloud Messaging - push delivered to the device, but device not displaying the push notification

Tags: php, android, curl, google-cloud-messaging

I have some server side code with which I am trying to create a push notification.  And the result looks like this:

```
{"multicast_id":8714083978034301091,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"r‌​esults":[{"message_id":"0:1350807053347963%9aab4bd8f9fd7ecd"}]}
```

and here is the PHP code I used to send that push notification. By the way the push didn't happen so I am trying to figure out why:

```
$url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';

$device_ids = array( $device_id );

$t_data = array();
$t_data['message'] = 'Someone commented on your business.';

$t_json = array( 'registration_ids' => $device_ids , 'data' => $t_data );

// Open connection
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array( 'Authorization: key=my_key', 'Content-Type: application/json' ) );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $t_json ) );

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

// Execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);    

if ($result === FALSE)
{   
   die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
}

// Close connection
curl_close($ch);
```

Here is the part of the manifest which deals with Google cloud messaging:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.problemio"
    android:versionCode="82"
    android:versionName="2.2.82" >

    <supports-screens  android:largeScreens="true"   android:normalScreens="true"  android:smallScreens="true"/> 

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="16"/>
    <!-- <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="xx"/>  -->

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <!-- Required permission to use in-app billing. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />



    <permission android:name="com.problemio.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" 
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.problemio.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />


    <!-- App receives GCM messages. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" /> 
    <!-- GCM requires a Google account. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <!-- Keeps the processor from sleeping when a message is received. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" /> 







    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:theme="@style/CustomTheme" 
        android:name="MyApplication"
        android:debuggable="true"
                >

        <!--  For Google Cloud Messaging -->
        <receiver android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
          <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <category android:name="com.problemio" />
          </intent-filter>
        </receiver>   

        <service android:name=".GCMIntentService" />
        <!--  End of Google Cloud Messaging -->
```

EDIT:

Here is my whole GCMIntentService class:

```
package com.problemio;

import static com.google.android.gcm.GCMConstants.ERROR_SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE;
import static com.google.android.gcm.GCMConstants.EXTRA_ERROR;
import static com.google.android.gcm.GCMConstants.EXTRA_REGISTRATION_ID;
import static com.google.android.gcm.GCMConstants.EXTRA_SPECIAL_MESSAGE;
import static com.google.android.gcm.GCMConstants.EXTRA_TOTAL_DELETED;
import static com.google.android.gcm.GCMConstants.EXTRA_UNREGISTERED;
import static com.google.android.gcm.GCMConstants.INTENT_FROM_GCM_LIBRARY_RETRY;
import static com.google.android.gcm.GCMConstants.INTENT_FROM_GCM_MESSAGE;
import static com.google.android.gcm.GCMConstants.INTENT_FROM_GCM_REGISTRATION_CALLBACK;
import static com.google.android.gcm.GCMConstants.VALUE_DELETED_MESSAGES;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import com.google.android.gcm.GCMBaseIntentService;

import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.IntentService;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.PowerManager;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import utils.GCMConstants;

public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService 
{

public GCMIntentService() 
{
        super(ProblemioActivity.SENDER_ID);
}

@Override
  protected void onRegistered(Context ctxt, String regId) {
    Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "onRegistered: " + regId);
    Toast.makeText(this, regId, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }

  @Override
  protected void onUnregistered(Context ctxt, String regId) {
    Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "onUnregistered: " + regId);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onMessage(Context ctxt, Intent message) {
    Bundle extras=message.getExtras();

    for (String key : extras.keySet()) {
      Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(),
            String.format("onMessage: %s=%s", key,
                          extras.getString(key)));
    }
  }

  @Override
  protected void onError(Context ctxt, String errorMsg) {
    Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "onError: " + errorMsg);
  }

  @Override
  protected boolean onRecoverableError(Context ctxt, String errorMsg) {
    Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "onRecoverableError: " + errorMsg);

    return(true);
  } 

  private static void generateNotification(Context context, String message, String title ) 
  {
        int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis(); // can change this to a future time if desired

        NotificationManager notificationManager = 
                (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, ProblemioActivity.class);

        // set intent so it does not start a new activity
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);        
        Uri defaultSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);            

         Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
         .setContentTitle(title)
         .setContentText(message)
         .setContentIntent(intent)
         .setSmallIcon(icon)
         .setLights(Color.YELLOW, 1, 2)
         .setAutoCancel(true)
         .setSound(defaultSound)
         .build();

        notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
}
```

}

But not matter what I try the push notification does not appear on the physical device.  Any ideas why not and how I can make it appear on the device?

Comment: here the success means the server succeeded in posting the cloud message to google severs. I don't think there is any way for the server to know if the push message got through.

Comment: @KKD thanks - the strange thing is that if the curl succeeded, then I can't figure out why the phone does not get the push notification :)

Comment: I can think of two possible scenarios....(1) The phone is not connected to internet (which I am sure you checked).........(2) the wifi you are connected to, is firewalled......

Comment: @KKD interesting but neither is the case :)...I am breaking my brain on it :)

Comment: Please do.... I am also interested in knowing the answer... :)

Comment: @KKD do you know if there may be something extra that has to be done on the code in the app that works after the curl call is made?

Comment: Have you added Custom permission and Broadcast receiver for the GCM message? Inside broadcast receiver you can pop-up a toast or notification or alert Dialog to verify..

Comment: @KKD you mean in the manifest? Yes I am pretty sure I did. Just added it to my original question. Or is there something else I need to do?

Comment: @KKD I think I might be understanding what is happening. I only used a basic GCMIntentService. But I didn't overwrite any of the BroadcastReceiver code - that is probably what I have to do, right?

Comment: Yes... You need to create a broadcast receiver for this.. that will call the service.... you can may be print the logs in BroadcastReceiver itself.... and one more thing is you can differentiate the registration and receive intents by intent.getAction() inside BroadcastReceiver

Comment: @KKD in the logs, it shows that the phone received the push notification. But for some reason, the phone just doesn't display the notification.

Comment: It will not display the notification as you expect.... if you want a status bar notification you need to use Notification Manager... and the message that you send as cloud message is inside intent.getExtras()... If you want I can post a sample code here....

Comment: @KKD I just posted my onMessage() - is that not how it should be? Or is there other code that needs to be added? By the way, huge thanks to you for sticking with me on this question and helping!!!

Comment: You need to programmatically generate the notification to actually put it in the status bar. Sometimes you might _not_ want to display a notification when receiving a GCM message. Refer to http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html

Comment: @unexpected62 There is a lot there, but I didn't find in which method to put the NotificationManager code.  Does it go into the onMessage() ?  Also, in my case, I do want to display the notification right away.

Comment: I left an answer for you, sorry for just linking you before.

Comment: add to onMessage() the call to the notification function, e.g. generateNotification(Context context, String message, "Test" ).

Comment: @KKD thank you for your help. I have upvoted some of your other answers

Comment: It is my pleasure @Genadinik. I am glad you found the solution :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to add to onMessage() the call to the notification function, like this:

```
@Override
protected void onMessage(Context ctxt, Intent message) {
    Bundle extras=message.getExtras();

    for (String key : extras.keySet()) {
      Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(),
            String.format("onMessage: %s=%s", key,
                      extras.getString(key)));
    }
    generateNotification(ctxt, extras.getString("message"), "test title");
```

}

Comment: that did it - thank you! I am only allowed to award the bounty in 17 hours. I will give it to you then :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to actually manually generate a notification in the `onMessage()` method. onMessage() is just a method that will be called when your app received the tickle from the server. You may not always want to generate a visible status bar notification to the user. So Google gave the flexibility to only put the notification if you want. Regardless, here's code that will help you generate this notification. You can tweak this for your needs, obviously.

```
private void generateNotification(Context context, String message)
{
    // put an icon for your notification in your res/drawable folder
    // and then get the icon as an int
    int icon = R.drawable.notif_icon_name;
    long when = System.currentTimeMillis(); // can change this to a future time if desired
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
         .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);
    String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, BaseActivity.class);
    // set intent so it does not start a new activity
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
        | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
    notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I have something similar there like you suggested. I added my code into my original question. Is there something I am not doing right in my code by any chance?

Comment: thank you - the other answer helped me, but I will go through some of your other questions/answers and upvote you :)

Comment: How is what he said any different?